# Some buttons are missing due to HTTP 403 Forbidden for the sprite SVGs

Tags: support, design

I'm missing some buttons like the Home button or the up- and downvote buttons. They are only invisible and I can still click on them, but it is a bit annoying.

I've already tried a different browser. What else can I try?

This is what it looks like:

> [image: screenshot of page with missing buttons]

Screenshot of blocked requests:

> [image: screenshot of blocked requests]

Comment: Any blocked requests in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: yes, I added a screen shot, if it is what you mean

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. Are you running any ad blockers or privacy addons in your browsers?

Comment: I don't have any tool installed in my browser, but this is a PC from the office, so there is maybe somewhere an Adblocker or something else. But there wasn't changes in the past weeks and I hav the problems since a few days.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to pay a visit to your office's IT department and ask them to take a look.

Comment: I am going to do that, thanks for your help